# vba UserForm page transitions

Tags: vba, excel

As far as I can tell, this is an unanswered question around several sites, although I suspect the answer might be very obvious.

When using pages on a VBA UserForm, there are two settings/properties I can change in the property boxes - transitionEffect and transitionPeriod.

I've tried changing both in a variety of combinations and the effect on the form is completely non-apparent.

Even with transitionPeriod set to 10000 there is no effect.

Is it simply because VBA uses ticks and on new machines the ticks go way too quick?

Comment: There is an effect, but it's almost instantaneous even at 10000 (seen better if a picture background is set). It does not appear like it depends on the timeout setting. The timeout should not depend on computer speed either, it's been documented to be expressed in milliseconds for ages.

Comment: Seems it's rendered useless at the minute then, I guess my fancy menu switching won't look so fancy after all :D